# STM32L4 - HAL_I2C_STATE_BUSY_RX issue

Tags: stm32, i2c

I'm having trouble with i2c communication. In my i2c bus, i have 4 boards (STM32L4 Sensortiles) and  sometimes one of them blocks the bus and the others stop communicating consequently. When I reset that one that blocks the bus, all boards starting working again.

In my debugs, this bug happened when **HAL_I2C_GetState(&hi2c3)** returns **HAL_I2C_STATE_BUSY_RX**, even my others i2c functions **HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive_IT** and **HAL_I2C_Slave_Transmit_IT** returns **HAL_OK**:

[image]

Any ideas what Im doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Using libraries like HAL leads to problems like this one. Why?

1. HAL users feel free from knowing your hardware as magic library will do everything for you.
2. HAL users usually do not know how the peripheral works and how to debug it.
3. HAL users do not bother to go through the magic HAL function to see what the problem is.

Posting some images form debugger will not help.

What you need to do:

1. Get even the cheapest logic analyzer (there are $10 on ebay) and record the communication. See if the slave keeps the clock or data line low. If yes toggle the clock pin 9 times to unblock the line
2. If nothing helps reset the I2C peripheral using RCC register (it has to be implemented on all connected boards).